# Extract stream to JSON in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Help figuring out how to convert following string to JSON in javascript . I require date(20181218-20181228) and its corresponding price(formattedPrice=$469). Thanks!

```
  20181218-20181228={currencyCode=USD, totalPrice=469.4, formattedPrice=$469, cheapest=false}, 
    20181218-20181226={currencyCode=USD, totalPrice=469.4, formattedPrice=$469, cheapest=false}, 
    20181218-20181227={currencyCode=USD, totalPrice=451.4, formattedPrice=$451, cheapest=false},
```

Tried adding quotes and : to the text but facing error while parsing because the key(20181218-20181228) isn't specific

Comment: Where do you get such a strange string from? Can you modify the source?

Comment: No it is not modifiable. It is based on reponse from an external API

Comment: So what have you tried? Objective here is to help others fix their code, not to be a free code writing service

Comment: Tried replacing equals to : and adding quotes around the text before and after equals, so as to convert to JSON format

Comment: So include what you have tried so far in the question along with errors produced

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.split()` and `.reduce()` like this;

```
function parseWeirdString(str) {
    return str.split(/},?/g).reduce((obj, row) => {
        const rowParts = row.split(/\={/);

        if (rowParts.length > 1) {
          obj[rowParts[0].trim()] = rowParts[1].split(/,/g).reduce((innerObj, keyValue) => {
              const keyValueParts = keyValue.split(/=/);

              innerObj[keyValueParts[0].trim()] = keyValueParts[1].trim();

              return innerObj;
            }, {});
        }

        return obj;
      }, {});
}
```

Should return an object like this:

```
{
  "20181218-20181228": {
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "totalPrice": "469.4",
    "formattedPrice": "$469",
    "cheapest": "false"
  },
  "20181218-20181226": {
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "totalPrice": "469.4",
    "formattedPrice": "$469",
    "cheapest": "false"
  },
  "20181218-20181227": {
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "totalPrice": "451.4",
    "formattedPrice": "$451",
    "cheapest": "false"
  }
}
```

Note that all values are strings including `"true"` and `"false"`. and if the values have commas etc then this will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all = with : using replace all, Remove "," in the end, Put { and } in start and end. All the non-number and non-boolean values should be put in "". You can write a regex for that. Let me know if you need help in that.

```
objstr = `{"20181218-20181228":{"currencyCode":"USD", "totalPrice":469.4, "formattedPrice":"$469", "cheapest":false}, 
    "20181218-20181226":{"currencyCode":"USD", "totalPrice":469.4, "formattedPrice":"$469", "cheapest":false}}`;

//replace, remove last , ,,,   Put {} in start and end    ,,,,

obj = JSON.parse(objstr);
console.log(obj);
```

You can use below Regex to parse this object. I have created a custom regex for your need which you can customize. There are some other options like eval but are not secure. btw since you are new so informing you that you can upvote(like) answers helping you :)

```
objstr22 = `{20181218-20181228={currencyCode=USD, totalPrice=469.4, formattedPrice=$469, cheapest=false}, 
20181218-20181226={currencyCode=USD, totalPrice=469.4, formattedPrice=$469, cheapest=false}, 
20181218-20181227={currencyCode=USD, totalPrice=451.4, formattedPrice=$451, cheapest=false}}`;

objstr22 = objstr22
  .replace(/ /g, "")
  .replace(/([\-\w\d]+)=/g, '"$1"=')
  .replace(/=([\w\d\.\$]+)/g, ':"$1"')
  .replace(/=([[{])/g, ":$1");
console.log(objstr22);
let obj22 = JSON.parse(objstr22);

for (o of Object.keys(obj22)) {
  console.log(o, obj22[o]);
}
```

Comment: Is there an faster approach to adding " " ?. There are no quotes in the incoming string as well.

Comment: You that you can upvote(like) answers helping you :)